# How to load &gt & lt in to another xml using xslt2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

**Input XML**

```
&lt;note&gt;
&lt;from&gt;Example&lt;/from&gt;
&lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt;
&lt;body&gt;XSLT conversion&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/note&gt;
```

**Output XML expected.**

```
<xml>
  <data>
    <column1>
      &lt;note&gt;
      &lt;from&gt;Example&lt;/from&gt;
      &lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt;
      &lt;body&gt;XSLT conversion&lt;/body&gt;
      &lt;/note&gt;
    </column1>
  </data>
</xml>
```

Current XSLT we are using which we have some issues loading the input. (If the input is straight XML we do not have any issue copying it, its only with the encoded XML).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xml>
      <data>
        <column1>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/node()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </column1>
      </data>
    </xml>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you can use `unparsed-text()` to process your input. If you pass the path to the text file as a parameter, you can use either text or XML input with the same stylesheet.

- If the input is text, pass the path to the text file as the parameter. You still have to pass XML to the stylesheet, so you can use the stylesheet itself as input.
- If the input is XML, don't pass a value to the parameter.

**Input** (test.txt)

```
&lt;note&gt;
&lt;from&gt;Example&lt;/from&gt;
&lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt;
&lt;body&gt;XSLT conversion&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/note&gt;
```

**XSLT 2.0** (using the stylesheet as the xml input and passing `test.txt` as the `input` param)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="input" select="''" as="xs:string"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xml>
            <data>
                <column1>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$input">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="unparsed-text($input)"/>                           
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </column1>
            </data>
        </xml>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<xml>
   <data>
      <column1>&amp;lt;note&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;from&amp;gt;Example&amp;lt;/from&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;heading&amp;gt;Reminder&amp;lt;/heading&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;body&amp;gt;XSLT conversion&amp;lt;/body&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;/note&amp;gt;
</column1>
   </data>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 1):

You *"Input XML"* isn't XML at all - it is just a piece of text.

A valid XML document must have a *single root element*, and yours has no elements at all unless there is something in the file other than the text you have shown.

If you wrap your XML in a dummy root element, like this

```
<root>
&lt;note&gt;
&lt;from&gt;Example&lt;/from&gt;
&lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt;
&lt;body&gt;XSLT conversion&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/note&gt;
</root>
```

then you can transform it using this stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xml>
      <data>
        <column1>
          <xsl:value-of select="root"/>
        </column1>
      </data>
    </xml>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get this output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
   <data>
      <column1>
&lt;note&gt;
&lt;from&gt;Example&lt;/from&gt;
&lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt;
&lt;body&gt;XSLT conversion&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/note&gt;
</column1>
   </data>
</xml>
```

Comment: thanks , it will not have xml tag at all , all of them ('<','>') converted to &gt , &lt .. but this XSLT code worked for regular xml ,not &gt ,&lt xml.. got empty file as output.any help?

Comment: @ChristopherDavid: As it stands, your data isn't XML and so can't be processed with XSLT. If all you want to do is wrap it in `xml/data/column1` then just write a program that prints that out.